# Не работает кнопка в юнити UI

Tags: unity3d, ui

Создал на Unity Хоррор с fps контроллером, так вот в меню всё хорошо как только я умираю меня переносит в главное меню. Кажется всё окей но нет кнопка не работает. EventSystem на месте

Comment: Приведите какие то скриншоты вашей менюшки,инспектора с параметрами кнопок, логику перехода в главное меню после смерти

Answer (score 0):

Выберите на сцене объект с EventSystem - справа снизу вы сможете в рантайме посмотреть все данные из него (например, на что наведён курсор). Так вы поймете отрабатывается ли вообще наведение на кнопки и может они банально чем-то перекрыты. Если наведение работает нормально (в EventSystem появляется имя кнопки при наведении), то ищите проблему в подписке и отписке